# if ($.isNumeric(dataArray[i].value) ){}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, validation

```
<form id='myform'>
  <input name='letra'value='a'/>
  <input name='letra' value='b'/>
  <input name='number1' value='1'/>
  <input name='letra' value='d'/>
  <input name='number2' value=''/>
  <input name='letra' value='f'/>
</form>
```

and my jquery is

```
var dataArray = $("#myform").serializeArray(),
len = dataArray.length;


for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(dataArray[i].name == 'number1' || dataArray[i].name == 'number2' ) {
        if($.isNumeric(dataArray[i].value)){
            alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' is number');
        }else
            alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' not number');      
    }else
        alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' si tiene');
    }
```

console tells me that :

Uncaught TypeError: $.isNumeric is not a function

ani help please? is for optimize my source c:, or i dont know how to use $.isNumeric??

Comment: Provide your code here as text and not image. You can use the code formatting tool while you edit/enter your post.

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use in your application?

Comment: is the 1.11.3.min.js

Comment: it seems to run fine with 1.11.1

Comment: ill check it, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some other bit of code which could cause the trouble? Is $ conflicted? Try jQuery.isNumeric?

The code you posted works fine for me

```js
var dataArray = $("#myform").serializeArray(),
len = dataArray.length;


for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(dataArray[i].name == 'number1' || dataArray[i].name == 'number2' ) {
        if($.isNumeric(dataArray[i].value)){
            alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' is number');
        }else
            alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' not number');      
    }else
        alert('campo '+dataArray[i].name +' si tiene');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform'>
  <input name='letra'value='a'/>
  <input name='letra' value='b'/>
  <input name='number1' value='1'/>
  <input name='letra' value='d'/>
  <input name='number2' value=''/>
  <input name='letra' value='f'/>
</form>
```